# What does Bison's $<num>$ do>?

Tags: bison

I explore Bison's syntax and there is a question about some construction like

```
       bodystmt:
       {
           $<num>$ = parser->line;
       }
```

I know about $$ and $1 and that num is a type.. but this is something new for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an explicit type tag that overrides the declared type for that value.  So if you have:

```
%union {
    int  num;
    char *str;
}

%type<str> bodystmt

%%

bodystmt: { $<num>$ = ... }
```

it sets the `num` field in the union instead of the `str` field as declared by the `%type` delcaration in the header.  Of course, other uses of the value (eg, as `$1` in some other rule that uses `bodystmt` on the rhs) will access the `str` field, so they'd need be changed to be `$<num>1` instead to avoid undefined behavior.

Where this is useful is when you have embedded actions that have different types:

```
%type<num> foo baz
%%
rule: { $<num>$ = 5; } foo { $<str>$ = "bar" } baz {
                     x = $<num>1;  /* gets the 5 stored in the first action */
                     y = $2;       /* the result of rule 'foo' */
                     z = $<str>3;  /* the string '"bar"' */
                     printf("%d %d\n", $2, $4); }

foo: A B { $$ = $<num>0; /* gets the value stored by the action just before the 'foo' in the rule that triggers this rule }

baz: { $<num>$ = strlen($<str>0); } foo  /* the <num> here is redundant and has no effect */
```

So the above code (besides doing a bunch of useless stuff for illustration) will, if it gets the input `ABAB`, print `5 3`